# Escaping single quote in shell accessed via adb

Tags: shell, adb, su

I need to check a directory's existence via adb. I'm passing adb the directory name via a program (which builds the adb command) and checking the return value.

Directories with spaces aren't an issue:

```
adb shell su -c  [ -d  "'/sdcard/test\ dir'" ] && echo 'true'
```

returns true.

However I also need to check for directories with apostrophes:

```
adb shell su -c  [ -d  "'/sdcard/joe\'s\ dir'" ] && echo 'true'
```

returns:

```
/system/bin/sh: no closing quote
```

I've tried other SO solutions to escape the '  w/o success. Possible solutions or alternate approaches appreciated.

Comment: The proper escaping rules for nested shell commands depend on the host system (OS and shell) as well which you did not specify.

Comment: The "via adb"  is "android debug bridge", the shell is android sh. Apologies.

Comment: I was talking about your *host system* as in the computer you connect your android device to.